# German style guide for capitalization rules of UI elements

Tags: labels, content, style-guide, capitalization

I want to improve the text consistency in our software, because over time some things got messed up and we have different styles for example in captalization of UI elements (controls). I find a lot of style guides for English capitalization rules (Microsoft, IBM, Apple, ...) but not for German.

Do the english rules for title and sentence case also apply to German?

Can you name me some sources for german style guides?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Microsoft's take on the writing style guide for the German language you can take a look at the following link (page 20):

download.microsoft.com/download/f/3/8/f389007c-663a-4774-96e0-dcbaf19ac436/deu-deu-styleguide.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to UXSE. For completeness of the answer it would be good to summarize the answer to the question, and if you have found other references you can add it to your answer as well :)

Comment: I know the German styleguide from Microsoft, but it does not offer detailed instructions for UI elements and only references the German capitalization rules. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to cross post or move your question to the [German Language Stack Exchange](https://german.stackexchange.com/), but since the German language capitalizes all nouns, you could argue the case that you would use more capitalization where possible.

You can take a look at news sites like [this one](https://www.tagesschau.de/) for a general understanding of sentence and title capitalization, but it seems like their title and sentence capitalization rules are the same, in general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not know about the German Language Stack Exange. But now its obvious to post my question there.